# Showing hidden fields dependant on radio button

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get a hidden text field to appear upon a radio button being clicked.

I am new to jQuery and have been looking at different examples of and tutorials of code, but they all differ slightly through the different releases of jQuery and have become muddled on which of my code is new and which is old. Some suggest change and others click (which to me makes more sense but I'm probably completely wrong).

Here's a section of my code:

First, the form:

```
Are you eighteen or above?<br/>
<input type="radio" id="age" name="age" value="yes"/>Yes<br/>
<input type="radio" id="age" name="age" value="no"/>No<br/><br/>

<!-- if no is selected the below text form shall appear -->     
<div id="agetext">
    If no, please tell us your date of birth:<br/>
    <textarea id="age" name="agetext" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea><br/><br/>
</div>
```

Secondly, the script (which is in the head tag):

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $("#agetext").hide();
    $("#agetextgo").click(function() 
    {
        if ( $('input[name="age"]:checked').val() == "no")
        {
            $("#agetext").show();
        }
        else ( $('input[name="age"]:checked').click() == "yes")
            $("#agetext").hide();
    });
```

Comment: `$('input[name="age"]:checked').click() == "yes"` you can't do that, you're creating a `click` event into that input. And BTW, where is the element `#agetextgo` in your HTML code ?

Comment: The element "#agetextgo" shouldn't have been in this, it's not in my code. Should be just agetext. Which I suspect is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do this:-

```
$("#agetext").hide();
$("input[name=age]").click(function() 
    {
        if ( $("#age1").attr('checked'))
            $("#agetext").hide();
        else
            $("#agetext").show();
    });
```

### [LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/XWN7U/)

Comment: the second `if` should be an `else`, the two elements can't be checked at the same time

Answer (score 1):

**just change id of two radio button two radio button with same id is invalid....**

html for you

```
<input type="radio" id="age1" name="age" value="yes"/>Yes<br/>
<input type="radio" id="age2" name="age" value="no"/>No<br/><br/>
```

here is the jquery for this

```
$("#age1").click(function() 
    {
        if ( $("#age1").attr('checked'))
            $("#agetext").show();
    });

   $("#age2").click(function() 
    {
        if ( $("#age2").attr('checked'))
            $("#agetext").hide();
    });
```

Comment: Just made the changes, didn't work. It doesn't matter than I'm using WAMP?

Answer (score 1):

Please See here: **demo** http://jsfiddle.net/Yu7fN/6/

You have multiple syntactical issues I have resolved them but still can be improved. cheers! (hope this helps)

**jquery code**

```
$(function() {

    $("#agetext").hide();

    $(".age").click(function() {
        alert($('input[name="age"]:checked').val());
        if ($('input[name="age"]:checked').val() == "no")
            $("#agetext").show();
        else if ($('input[name="age"]:checked').val() == "yes") 
            $("#agetext").hide();


    });
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code have some mistakes:

- multiples HTML elements with the same ID (input radio),this is not valid,
- you're using an `"#agetextgo` element wich is not present in your page
- `$('input[name="age"]:checked').click() == "yes"` is not correct, a `click` couldn't be equal to a string value

I've done a working demo on jsfiddle, have a look http://jsfiddle.net/pomeh/5DuQB/1/

The code used in the demo is

```
<form>
Are you eighteen or above?<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="age" value="yes"/>Yes<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="age" value="no"/>No<br/><br/>
    <div id="agetext">
        If no, please tell us your date of birth:<br/>
        <textarea id="age" name="agetext" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea><br/><br/>
     </div>
</form>
```

And

```
var $div = jQuery("#agetext");

// hidden by default
$div.hide();

// when a click occur on an input[type=radio] element
jQuery("form").on("click", "input[type=radio]", function() {
    // does the element clicked has the value "yes" ?
    if ($(this).val()==="yes") {
        $div.hide();
    }
    else {
        $div.show();
    }
});​
```

Comment: Thank you, I just ended up with lots of snippets of code from through out different examples! I've still not got it working on WAMP but can see that this works from the demo, cheers!